# How to avoid bottom overflow in flutter columns within a GridView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-column

I though I had understood how flutter columns and rows work but I am unable to resolve the following bottom overflow in my column consisting of an Image- and two Textwidgets.

The widgets are arranged in a grid and  should look like this but with bigger images:

[image]

But once I increase the radius of the image circles I get bottom overflow like here:

[image]

This is the code of the widget with throw the errors:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Column(children: [
          InkWell(
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(ingredient.imgSrc,
                  imageRenderMethodForWeb: ImageRenderMethodForWeb.HttpGet),
              radius: 34,
            ),
            onTap: widget.onTap,
          ),
          Text(
            ingredient.name,
            style: TextStyle(color: textColor),
          ),
          Text(
            "g",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: textColor,
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
```

And this is the parent grid widget which contains the tiles:

```
Card( margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: new GridView.count(
              //     primary: true,
              //    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              mainAxisSpacing: 3,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
              children: [
                ...getAllIngredientTiles(), // here I assign the widget list
                Padding(
                    child: SizedBox(
                        width: 16,
                        height: 16,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: _openAddIngredientScreen,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.add,
                            size: 36,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(CircleBorder()),
                            padding:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(2)),
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                Colors.teal), // <-- Button color,
                          ),
                        )),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 22, right: 22, bottom: 22, top: 0)),
                //
              ],
            ))
```

What I tried:

- Wrapping the Column with a Container and set height manually
- Wrapping each of the widgets inside the Column with Containers/SizedBoxes with fixed height
- Wrapping with Expanded

Whatever I do I cant make the column increase its height and make the elements fit into it.

I read a lot of other related questions but the answers did not work for me. I would be very thankful for any suggestions which allow me to keep the grid and increase the image sizes without overflow.

Comment: Can you show the GridView code where this widget is being populated? @finisinfinitatis

Comment: @pblead26 Sure! I added the code for the parent GridVi.ew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to achieve what I want.
In order to increase the height of the tiles I made use of the `mainAxisExtent` property of SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount:

```dart
GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                    mainAxisExtent: 150 // <-- this works!
                    ...
                )
```

It was the only working way for me to increase the tile height and prevent bottom overflow. Now it looks as it should:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.Just chnage your widget to my widget.

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
  child: GridView.builder(
    itemCount: 7,
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    ),
    itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
      return Container(
        height: 120,
        width: 100,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              child: Image.network(
                'https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*-6WdIcd88w3pfphHOYln3Q.png',
                height: 50,
                width: 30,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              'Product Name',
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              '9',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used your code but Flutter wont let me omit "shrinkWrap = true" like it is in your code. Without it I get the error 'Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.'. However when I add shrinkWrap I have the same bevior as before: I cant increase the radius without getting Bottom Overflow

Comment: Your problem is solved or not by using my solution?

Comment: It is not solved. It leaves me with the same problem as before